# Correct way to clear android notification actions in android P?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-9.0-pie

I have an ongoing notification with a "Cancel" action. It looks something like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder progressNotif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, BackupService.BACKUP_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION);
...
...
// adding an action
progressNotif.addAction(cancelAction);
```

Next, after the job is over, I want to remove the "Cancel" action.
What I was trying was this:

`progressNotif.mActions.clear();`

But recently, Android Studio is giving me this error:

> Builder.mActions can only be accessed from within the same library
>   group (groupId=com.android.support)

This will probably cause a problem in Android Pie and above.
What does this error mean? How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin, you can extend the `NotificationCompat.Builder` class like this:

```
@SuppressLint ("RestrictedApi")
fun NotificationCompat.Builder.clearActions () {
    mActions.clear()
}
```

Then you can just simply call

```
progressNotif.clearActions()
```

Comment: Ok, I will try. I am thinking of migrating my project to kotlin soon.

Comment: You can mix Kotlin with Java in your project. No need to migrate everything now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the notification ID, you can call cancel with the notification manager.

```
final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
```